# cloudwatch lambda schedule on different environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to trigger the lambda by using cloud watch event rule at different time schedule, using different environmental variable.

For example,

Cloud Watch Event Rule Schedule 1:

at 9 am, trigger lambda A using lambda environmental variable: key_1:value_a;

Cloud Watch Event Rule Schedule 2:

at 10 am, trigger lambda A using lambda environmental variable: key_1:value_b;

I am using cloud formation to configure the resource. I've done some research on configuring lambda environmental variable through CW schedule, or setting up condition on lambda environmental variable for certain schedules, but I didn't find a feasible way to do it. Is there anyone have some ideas about it?

Answer (score 4):

> but I didn't find a feasible way to do it.

Sadly,  you **can't set environmental variables** of a lambda function through CloudWatch Events.

However, for each CW Event rule you can setup a **Constant (JSON text)** value to be passed to your function. This should be a good substitute for passing the env variables.

You haven't provided a **CFN template** with your CloudWatch Events rules, but in your **AWS::Events::Rule** resource you would have to setup [Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-input) values.

Also, I will just paste a screenshot from the console where to set it up for testing and development.

[image]

Comment: Downvotes without explanations nor an alternative answer are not helpful to anyone. Still it does not change the fact that you can't set env variables though CloudWatch Events for a lambda function.

Comment: I'm not the original poster, so I can't mark your answer. I was just expressing that your answer was helpful while I am trying to do the same thing as OP. we can't change the env variables based on different environments running the same code, but it is helpful to know about adding a constant input that can be changed based on the schedule event.

Comment: hey Marcin. I need to pass 2 env variables to my AWS Batch job in this target section. How can i achieve it. Check this one pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495042/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-scheduled-aws-batch-used-as-cloudwatch-ev

Comment: Very useful workaround! Thanks.

Comment: how to setup this with CDK