# How to pass environment variables to a scheduled AWS Batch used as cloudwatch event target

Tags: python-3.x, aws-batch, aws-event-bridge

I'm scheduling aws batch job as Cloudwatch event target in the aws console. The container need 2 environment variable to execute the job perfectly. So in aws event rule console, in the target section, there are 2 fields, constants and input transformers. So what is the best way to pass those environment variables to the container?
Below is the Python3 code of the container.

```
#src.py
import os

environment = os.environ.get('environment')
application = os.environ.get('application')
..
..
```